# Validate datetime-local input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/datetime-local), I should use `datetime-local` type for a date and a time input:

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

I can validate a date in laravel with this code (in a controller):

```
$this->validate($request, ['my_date' => 'required|date']);
```

But is there a way to validate a `datetime-local`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_format:format` or `date` to validate.  All date validation is performed by php [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

The best way to know for sure is to test this.  Create your `rules` function in the controller and test, that way you know for sure for *your* laravel version and *your* php version as you don't mention that information.

Answer (score 12):

In your example:

```
$this->validate($request, ['my_date' => 'date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i']);
```